# iPhone Div Background Image Centering?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm having a problem with [my site](http://savewithpride.com/dev/)'s footer.

As you can see on your iPhone (in Safari) the footer image is not displaying correctly and spanning the site's width.

This is the code for the footer:

```css
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 118px;
  background: #000000 url(../images/footer.png) top center !important;
  margin: 70px auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div style="width:1100px;height:118px;margin:auto;">
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
      <form action="http://SaveWithPride.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=0beccc5a2d913b0527a748edc&amp;id=cb6e398bc5" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email footer-field" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="enter your text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'enter your text'" required>
        <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button footer-submit"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div style="width:334px;height:118px;float:right;background:transparent;">
      <div class="socialtext">save with pride, socially:</div>
      <div class="twitter"></div>
      <div class="facebook"></div>
      <div class="footertext">© 2013 SaveWithPride.com&nbsp&nbspAll Rights Reserved.&nbsp&nbsp<a href="adamdworak.com">Design by A/D</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here? The footer background (as it appears now) does not stretch to the edge of the browser on iPhone and seems like its not centered. I am trying to get it centered and at 100% width as it shows on my computer.

Comment: Downvote for inappropriate language, Be civil.

Answer (score 0):

So the footer element background is not as wide as the screen? Try adding this:

```
.footer {
    background-size: 100% 100%; /* stretches background */
}
```

Comment: Neat, gave this a shot but it's still coming up a bit short on the right side on iphone.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try making the footer background black just to make sure the footer actually is 100% width. It's also short on the right side on my iPad. Is the footer in another element that could be keeping it short?

Answer (score 0):

Try it removing the width from the `.footer` css

Also if you wish to fit the page within iPhone screen change the width of the .footer child div to 940px as shown below

```
<div class="footer">
   <div style="width:940px;height:118px;margin:auto;">
```

I say change the width because .footer is set to 100% width which will be the equivalent of the iphone screen width therefore the image will stretch only to the screen width. The problem is that the child div may have a width bigger than the iPhone screen width which will require the user to scroll further right and is the reason why the image isn't stretched.